# How to process sensor data in LabVIEW? Every value is 255

Tags: byte, sensors, labview, spi, gyroscope

I'm trying to read data from the Yost Labs 3-Space Sensor Nano into LabVIEW via an NI MyRIO (1900). I was able to set up a sequence that communicates with the sensor through SPI. However, every time I run the program, it just spits out a single value of 255.

I think understand that I need to include something that allows all the bytes to be read. I just don't know how to go about it.

As an example, I'm trying to read the gyros (0x26) which have a return length of 12 and is a vector (float x3).

Here is my labview code
[image]

and [here is the manual for the sensor.](https://yostlabs.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/pdf/3-Space-Sensor-Users-Manual-Nano.pdf) The commands I'm using are on pages 29-33. In the image, 0x2B is 'read temperature'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Edit: i had messed up the wiring so now the output jumps between ~35 to 255. I'm still having trouble getting all 3 gyro values from the SPI read.

Comment: The express block that resets the sensor is not guaranteed to precede the loop because there is no data flow between them. The LabVIEW runtime can see two independent and parallel groups and may choose to execute them simultaneously (which on the wire might mean reset comes between loop commands) or in "reverse" order. Add a wire from reset block to create a terminal on the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting from Joe Friedrichsen in his comment:
*The express block that resets the sensor is not guaranteed to precede the loop because there is no data flow between them. The LabVIEW runtime can see two independent and parallel groups and may choose to execute them simultaneously (which on the wire might mean reset comes between loop commands) or in "reverse" order. Add a wire from reset block to create a terminal on the loop.*

Here's a picture of the fix.
[image]

You may wish to consider stringing the error wire through your program and wiring it to the stop terminal of the While Loop. Currently, your loop will keep running even if there's a fault in your hardware. Using the error wire would eliminate the need for the flat sequence structure.